# Tableau, need to pull data out of Sybase to merge with SQL Server

Tags: tableau-api, sybase

All -

I have a critical data source that lives in Sybase that I need to blend with sql server and/or Hadoop Data.

Has anyone successfully connected Sybase to Tableau?  I am able to sql query Sybase using dbeaver , but would like to find a way to automate the connection
.

I have tried connecting with the exact same jdbc credentials and it won’t work.  Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how they got it to work?

Comment: You could try using the ODBC driver

Comment: Did not work, unfortunately.  Do you know if you had to use a specific driver or special configuration to make it work?